# Getting Products by category id! Magento 2.1 REST

Tags: magento-2.1, products, rest-api, category-products

How can I get products of a specific category? For Example
If I hit
[https://www.example.com/index.php/rest/V1/categories/[category_id]/products](https://www.example.com/index.php/rest/V1/categories/%5Bcategory_id%5D/products)

it should return all products of the same Category [category_id] with all details.
But it is returning only SKU

```
[
    {
        "sku": "CN-101",
        "position": 1,
        "category_id": "6"
    },
    {
        "sku": "AA-102",
        "position": 1,
        "category_id": "6"
    },
    {
        "sku": "GY-105",
        "position": 1,
        "category_id": "6"
    },
    {
        "sku": "DR-107W",
        "position": 1,
        "category_id": "6"
    },
    {
        "sku": "DR-107G",
        "position": 1,
        "category_id": "6"
    }
]
```

Please guide me on how I'll get all products with details by category?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get the products of a specific category with this API call:

```
rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=category_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]={categoryId}
```

This should return all the infos about the products.