# Get All Products by Category ID or Name API

Tags: magento2

I am asking this, but with some addition.

[Getting Products by category id! Magento 2.1 REST](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/205308/getting-products-by-category-id-magento-2-1-rest)

I am getting All Categories with ( I am using Magento 2 sample data )

`http://www.myshop.com/rest/V1/categories`

In that result for example i took Female Tops category which has id of 21 and ran request

`http://www.myshop.com/rest/V1/categories/21/products`

this returns me all products (50) with their SKU, But i need all data from products.

Now i tried couple of things to achieve this:

**1. Get all products by their SKU which i get from their category**

`http://www.myshop.com/rest/V1/products?
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=sku&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=MH01&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][field]=sku&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][1][value]=MH02&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][2][field]=sku&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][2][value]=MH03` ...

It works, But the problem with this is it might get HTTP Error 414 URL is too long
(if there are too many products) and i think is not very efficient.

**2. Get all products by their category ID**

`http://www.myshop.com/rest/V1/products?
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=category_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=21`

This returns me 0 Products and I think I understand why, its because they are not in this category rather they are in child category (i saw that in custom_attributes key `category_ids` (this is in fact where they "belong")), And also this will return me all products not just bundled as I want.

Is there a better way of getting products by their categories? Without writing new APIs. I just started using magento 2 APIs and maybe i overlooked something.

Comment: if you have gotten solution kindly post here. i am also facing same issues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to perform a search by SKU (first case) in a better way, you could use the LIKE condition as in the example in the official guides

```
GET http://<magento_host>/index.php/rest/V1/products?
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=name&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=%25Leggings%25&
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=like
```

To perform a search by category ids you can use the category Interface i.e.

```
GET /V1/categories/{categoryId}/products
```

Comment: But this will return me Products with name like Leggings, I need Products by Category ID or Category Name which i get from http://www.myshop.com/rest/V1/categories/21/products . Yes i know but that will return me Products SKU, and i need all product data

Comment: I'm sorry, I was suggesting how to solve the first point for a too long URL and didn't understand you wanted to search by category name. As far as I know you cannot search directly by category name, you first need to get the id.

Comment: No problem, i edited question i was at fault. I taught it was somehow possible. i do get the ID, and search by that ID , but the problem is getting all product details as i get only sku

Comment: Ok, i see now the problem of the call to category interface, but I don't understand the problem of the call `http://www.myshop.com/rest/V1/products?
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=category_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=21`. This returns all products data, not only their skus...

Comment: True, But the problem with that is if you do it on for example TOPS (from example data) it will return 0, while there are 50 items, and also this will return all items (their colors and everything)

Comment: Are you sure about the id you're using? I mean, if there are 50 items in that category but it returns 0, probably you're using a wrong id...

Comment: That is the problem i am getting 50 items `http://www.myshop.com/rest/V1/categories/21/products` with this with their sku which is exactly as on web, but when i do it like `http://www.myshop.com/rest/V1/products?
searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=category_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=21` it returns me 0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73027/discussion-between-sissy-and-mepo).

Comment: What happened to this? I dont see the expected solution in the chat. Did i miss something? How do i get the details of the items in parent id only?

Answer (score 5):

If you want specificate a search by category_id:

`GET http://<magento_host>/index.php/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=category_id&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=14&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq`