# Magento 2 : How to Fetch Particular Product Category Name via API

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

I want to access specified product category information using API.

Comment: Can you describe your requirement in some more details.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/213087/get-all-products-by-category-id-or-name-api/213093